# Xcode 6 Beta crashes app using core data when run on iPad 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

A couple of days ago I updated to Xcode 6 Beta 5 and of course iOS 8 Beta SDK Beta 5. It runs one of my Core Data apps just fine on the simulator and my test devices running iOS 8. But then I tried to run the app on a physical iPad (4th Gen) running iOS 7.1 and it crashed with this error.

> dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
>
> 0x2be730c4:  trap
> 0x2be730c8:  nop

So I tried to run it on an iPad Air 7.1 simulator and I didn't get the fatal error but I got the following console log after the app crashed.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
```

When I run the iPad Retina 7.1 Simulator - which should correspond to a 4th Gen iPad - it compiles and runs just fine! Also, it has no problem with any of the iPhones, simulated or not, running iOS 7.1! I never had any core data issues prior to beta 5.

I've cleaned the project, rebooted my Mac several times, and I still can't get it to run on my physical iPad or the iPad Air simulator on iOS 7.1.

I realize it could just be a really inconvenient bug, but I was wondering if maybe I was just overlooking something simple. I have a custom class that pulls from my core data entities and here is the code I use to call up the Managed Object Context:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void) startContext {
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
}
```

That's how I was showed to do it. Is that a bad way of loading the Managed Object Context for performing a fetch request? Is there a different way I should do it that maybe wouldn't cause these bugs?

Comment: And you have deleted the app off the device too?. This usually means either the store file is corrupt or the managed object model can't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Warren Burton. I feel kind of stupid. I thought I had deleted all instances of the app off of the simulators by using "Reset Content and Settings", but I guess I missed the iPad Air Simulator. I also forgot to delete it from the physical iPad. Once I deleted the two installs and re-built and ran, everything worked fine. So I guess my store files got corrupted when moving over to the new beta of iOS 8 SDK. It looks like the corruption only happened to installs on iOS 7, whereas iOS 8 installs made it through just fine.